# How to load an image/jpeg with retrofit and archictecture component?

Tags: android, image, retrofit2

I'm using archictecture Android Architecture Components. I want to load an image from my api.

this is the request on postman :

!https://ibb.co/WPJjpFm

I' am actually using retrofit but i don't known how to transform Responsebody to file.

```
@GET("image/{filename}")
    Call<ResponseBody> getImage(@Path("filename") String filename);
```

```
public MutableLiveData<File> retriveImageTest(String filename) {
        MutableLiveData data = new MutableLiveData<>();
        executor.execute(() -> {
            imageWebService.getImage(filename).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                   // How to deal with responsebody ?
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        });
        return data;
    }
```

What' s the best way to do it without breaking Android Architecture Components ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you loading images with Retrofit? Images are for Picasso or Glide, since it's very optimised to have cache and queues.

Comment: Is it possible to use Picasso directly in the repository ? what' s the " good practise" ?

Comment: The best practice is go use Picasso. Cause it's optimised for images, and is from the same family as OkHttp and Retrofit

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use Image loading libraries like Glide ,Picasso or Fresco to load images:
Using Glide, add this to your app gradle file

```
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

Then ,

```
Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```

For more info : [Glide docs](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/)